# manually rotating logfile with rsyslogd

Tags: log-files, debian-squeeze, logrotate, rsyslog

I want to force logfile rotation using `logrotate -f /var/log/syslog`, but it's only return tones of:

```
error: syslog:1 unknown option 'May' -- ignoring line
error: syslog:1 unexpected text
```

I know that on this system rsyslogd is running. How to rotate `/var/log/syslog`? I want it empty.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't tell `logrotate` which file to rotate on the command line.  You pass it a configuration file.  So in your case, `logrotate` is reading `/var/log/syslog` and trying to parse it as a config file and failing (hence your errors).

If you want to rotate `/var/log/syslog` it needs to be listed in a `logrotate` config file somewhere, and you just run `logrotate`.  If it rotated recently, then `logrotate -f` to force it to do it again.

Here's an example entry for `/var/log/syslog` from Debian,

```
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

So, you need that in a file, normally either `/etc/logrotate.conf` or as a file snippet in `/etc/logrotate.d` assuming your `/etc/logrotate.conf` points there, and then you just run `logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf`.

Since you're running Debian, this is probably all in place, and all you need to actually do is run `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` (note, this will rotate *every* log currently configured in logrotate).

If you **truly** only want to rotate `/var/log/syslog`, you will need to create a config file that just does that one log, based on the content of `/etc/logrotate.conf` + `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`.